# Pivoting on table with huge number of records

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot

I have the following tables:

```
Create Table A
(rpt_id number,
Acct_id number,
type vatchar2(10));


Create Table 2
(rpt_id number,
Acct_id number,
tp varchar2(10),
information varchar2(100));


Insert into A1 (RPT_ID,ACCT_ID,TYPE) values (1,11,'type1');
Insert into A1 (RPT_ID,ACCT_ID,TYPE) values (2,22,'type2');


Insert into A2 (RPT_ID,ACCT_ID,TP,INFORMATION) values (1,11,'billnum','2341');
Insert into A2 (RPT_ID,ACCT_ID,TP,INFORMATION) values (1,11,'billname','abcd');
```

I need to take information as below:

```
RPT_ID ACCT_ID billnum billname
------ ------- ------- --------
1       11      2341    abcd
```

This table will have a huge amount of data, around 200000 records in A1 and related records in A2 - atleast 4 to 5 rows for each RPT_ID.

Should I be creating a pivot direct from these two joins to improve performance?

So far I have used this approach:

```
Insert into t3
as select a2.*
     from a1
     join a2 on a1.rpt_id = a2.rpt_id and a1.ACCT_ID = a2.ACCT_ID
    where a1.type = 'type1';
```

Pivot on t3 to make the following structure and insert into t4 to use it later in the code.

```
RPT_ID ACCT_ID billnum billname
------ ------- ------- --------
1      11      2341    abcd
```

This is going full scan for the A2 table. Are there any ways to avoid a full scan? Will pivot have performance issues with huge data?

Comment: @jarlh thank you for formatting the question. Please help me how to format it so that I can write in formatted manner from next  time.

Comment: format your text correctly in your editing tool of choise. Select/Copy./Paste your code into your Q. Now with the code selected in the S.O. edit screen, click on the `{}` tool in the edit menu at the top of the edit screen. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is going full scan for A2 table, is there anything we can about
>   this ot avoid full scan

Have you created any indexes on the tables in question? If not, then a full table scan is the only option!

And remember: a full table scan can be *the fastest way to get the rows*. To see if that's the case, you need to get the [execution plan](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-create-an-execution-plan) for your query.

That said, the current process of loading the join into a third table, then pivoting the results into a forth is convoluted. And likely to be a lot slower than just running query.

If you want to pre-compute the pivot, you're better off with a `materialized view`. This stores the result of your query. And - provided you can make it `fast refresh on commit` - the database will update it after you run DML.

For example:

```
Create Table A1 (
  rpt_id number,
  Acct_id number,
  type varchar2(10)
);  

Create Table A2 (rpt_id number,
  Acct_id number,
  tp varchar2(10),
  information varchar2(100)
);

Insert into A1 (RPT_ID,ACCT_ID,TYPE) values (1,11,'type1');
Insert into A1 (RPT_ID,ACCT_ID,TYPE) values (2,22,'type2');

Insert into A2 (RPT_ID,ACCT_ID,TP,INFORMATION) values (1,11,'billnum','2341');
Insert into A2 (RPT_ID,ACCT_ID,TP,INFORMATION) values (1,11,'billname','abcd');

commit;

create materialized view log on a1 
  with rowid, sequence ( rpt_id,acct_id,type )
  including new values;
create materialized view log on a2
  with rowid, sequence ( rpt_id,acct_id,tp,information )
  including new values;

create materialized view mv 
refresh fast on commit
as
with rws as (
  select a1.type, a2.*
  from   a1
  join   a2 on a1.rpt_id = a2.rpt_id 
  and    a1.ACCT_ID = a2.ACCT_ID
)
  select type, rpt_id, acct_id, 
         max ( case when tp = 'billnum' then information end ) billnum, 
         max ( case when tp = 'billname' then information end ) billname,
         count(*)
  from   rws
  group  by type, rpt_id, acct_id;

Insert into A2 (RPT_ID,ACCT_ID,TP,INFORMATION) values (2,22,'billname','abcd');

commit;

select * from mv;

TYPE     RPT_ID    ACCT_ID    BILLNUM    BILLNAME    COUNT(*)   
type1            1         11 2341       abcd                  2 
type2            2         22 <null>     abcd                  1
```

If necessary you can create indexes on the materialized view itself, further improving performance.

*NB - Oracle Database does have a `pivot` clause, but this doesn't work with `fast refresh on commit`. You need the old-fashioned version.*

Comment: Thanks @Chris for detail explanation as always.

There is index on RPT_ID,ACCT_ID and I can see this has used in executions plan. 
I was not much sure about creating index on type as cardinality is too low and per of record with Type as "type" is almost 2 to 3 per. Is is worth creating index in such cases ?

Never thought about creating MV for pivot. I Will try this one gain some performance improvement.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying - there's 2-3 rows per type or only 2-3 types in the whole table?

Comment: I am only looking for one specific type value, i.e. Type1. 
also, cardinality is too low with respect to Type value.
select count(*) from a1;
668559
select count(*) from a1 where type='type1' ;
36855

Comment: Maybe? You need to try it out! If you're still stuck/unsure, post a question with the [execution plan](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-create-an-execution-plan) for the statement

Comment: It looks like my table a1 and a2 are too large with half almost 200000 rows, isn't creating MV log on this table will create space issue? as I am daily truncating and inserting this many rows in this tables.

Comment: MV log only store the changes since the last refresh. If you're refreshing `on commit` this means it's emptied at the end of every transaction. So storage is a non-issue for this. Plus your question proposes two extra tables; surely these cause just as much of a "space issue"?

Comment: Also: 200k rows is "pretty small" by today's standards. If you're struggling to find space to store these you've got bigger problems to worry about.